# How to summarise data in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, mapreduce

I'm trying to implement a summary view on to a large(ish) data set using AppEngine.

My model looks something like:

```
def TxRecord(db.Model):
    expense_type = db.StringProperty()
    amount = db.IntegerProperty()

def ExpenseType(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    total = db.IntegerProperty()
```

My datastore contains 100K instances of `TxRecord` and I'd like to summarise these by `expense_type`.

In sql it would be something like:

```
select expense_type as name, sum(amount) as total 
    from TxRecord
    group by expense_type
```

What I'm currently doing is using the [Python MapReduce framework](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to iterate over all of the `TxRecords` using the following mapper:

```
def generate_expense_type(rec):
    expense_type = type.get_or_insert(name, name = rec.expense_type)
    expense_type.total += rec.amount

    yield op.db.Put(expense_type)
```

This seems to work, but I feel I have to run it using a `shard_count` of 1 in order to ensure that the total isn't over written with concurrent writes.

Is there a strategy that I can use to over come this issue using AppEngine or is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mapreduce is the right approach. Counters, as David suggests, are one option, but they're not reliable (they use memcache), and they're not designed for massive numbers of counters to be kept in parallel.

Your current mapreduce has a couple of issues: First, `get_or_insert` executes a datastore transaction every time it's called. Second, you then update the amount outside the transaction and asynchronously store it a second time, generating the concurrency issue you were concerned about.

At least until reduce is fully supported, your best option is to do the whole update in the mapper in a transaction, like this:

```
def generate_expense_type(rec):
    def _tx():
      expense_type = type.get(name)
      if not expense_type:
        expense_type = type(key_name=name)
      expense_type.total += rec.amount
      expense_type.put()
    db.run_in_transaction(expense_type)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the MapReduce framework is a good idea.  You could use more than one shard if you utilize the counters provided by the MapReduce framework.  So instead of modifying the datastore each time, you could do something like this:

```
yield op.counters.Increment("total_<expense_type_name>", rec.amount)
```

After the MapReduce finishes (hopefully much more quickly than when you were using just one shard), then you can copy the finalized counters into your datastore entity.

Comment: I'm currently attempting something similar using memcache entries. What I couldn't work out with the op.counters was how to get hold of the counters in the callback handler...time for another question?

Answer (score 3):

MapReduce is great for offline processing of data, and I like David's solution for handling the counters (+1 upvote).

I just wanted to mention another option: process the data as it comes in.  Check out Brett Slatkin's [High Throughput Data Pipelines on App Engine](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/high-throughput-data-pipelines-appengine.html) talk from IO 2010.

I've implemented the technique in a simple framework ([slagg](https://bitbucket.org/thebobert/slagg)), you might find my example of [grouping with date rollup useful](https://bitbucket.org/thebobert/slagg/src/a41cc67326ce/examples/grouping_with_date_rollup.py).